# Why jquery ajax form submit return error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am new to ajax and jquery and I need to submit a form with ajax when a button "mainbutton" is clicked. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mainbutton").click(function(){
                $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
                {
                    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
                    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url : formURL,
                        type: "POST",
                        data : postData,
                        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                        {
                            alert("success");
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                        {
                            alert("error");      
                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
                });
                $("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit the form
            });
        });
```

when I try that I get Error and my form is not submitted and my servlet doPost() is not called. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: your form submit function is inside your button click function. I think that is a problem: try jsut to use the submit function (with a normal submit button) and see if that helps? Also: please post error messages if you get any.

Comment: By "I get Error", do you mean that the `alert("error")` statement is invoked? If so, the problem is not specifically with your code (most likely with the value of formURL) and the value of textStatus will tell you. If not, what do you mean?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why do you have an `ajax` method AND a `submit()` method? And why are you preventing the default action?

Comment: What the type of button `mainbutton`? button or submit?

Comment: Try this [http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/2cgesxav/](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/2cgesxav/) and see if it helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's working to me.  See Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/louisnovick/qyLmvjax/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mainbutton").click(function(){
            $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
            {
                var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
                var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url : '/echo/html/',
                    type: "POST",
                    data : postData,
                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                    {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                    {
                        alert("error");      
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            });
            $("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit the form
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="ajaxform">
    <label for="test">Test Input</label>
    <input type='text' name="test">
        <button type="submit" id="mainbutton">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

Comment: The OP's value for formURL is blank, which is legal; yours, whatever it is, apparently is not.

Comment: Sorry, when I first submitted it returned success.  Ill look at it again.

Comment: Utilizing the Jsfiddle API for testing POST data it is returning success.  See Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/louisnovick/qyLmvjax/13/